# How to stop an submit event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am calling a function when form is submitting.

```
$('#form-target').submit(function(){
    makechange();
    return false;
});
```

But in some case i want to stop this event.

Comment: See this relevant question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false

Comment: if there is an error in the `makechange()` function, this could happen..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$('#form-target').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```